# What happens if Minotaur attacks Phoenix?

Tags: chess-evolved

I have been addicted to Chess Evolved on Facebook lately. Some of the piece effects are extremely vague though.

What happens in the scenario below if White's Minotaur had attacked my Phoenix?

[image: chess evolved scenario]

The Phoenix effect says:

> On Death: Transform into PhoenixEgg and lose 3 morale.
>
> On Melee Death: Destroy the attacker.

However, the Minotaur effect says:

> On Champion Kill: Swap places with enemy King.

Which effect procs first? Does the Minotaur die? Does the King swap?

Answer (score 2):

All of the above.

The Minotaur dies, the king swaps, and the Phoenix turns to an egg